# What is the difference between processor time and clock time?

Tags: cpu, operating-systems, process, clock

I encountered the following section in my operating systems textbook:

> At any given point in time, while the program is executing, this
>   process can be uniquely characterized by a number of elements,
>   including the following:
>
> - Accounting information: May include the amount of processor time and clock time used, time limits, account numbers, and so on.

I am wondering what the difference is between processor time and clock time in this context?

I would greatly appreciate it if the knowledgeable members of this site could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Processor time** refers to the amount of time that the processor itself actually spends working on a task. As a program is executing, the processor is not necessarily being utilized at every second that the program runs – for example, this does not include the time spent waiting for disk or network I/O. Processor time is the sum total amount of time that the CPU was used, as opposed to **Clock time** (aka "wall-clock time" or "wall time"), which refers literally to regular time as you know it. If a program ran for 10 minutes, that is 10 minutes of clock time.